# Do you ever use Frequency Shifter plugins and how

Tags: plug-ins, frequency

Do you ever use frequency shifter plugins and how??

Answer (score 1):

I'd recently used the GRM tools FreqShift plugin to create a monster scream. The final sound was a mix of FreqShift, PitchAccum, SoundToys Crystallizer & some reverb. The "meat" of the sound was achieved using FreqShift though. It's great fun to use on voices or animals to create zombie or creature-ish textures.

You can listen to it here:
http://soundcloud.com/ntkeep/the-scream-before-after

The scream was layered under a mirror shattering so it was meant to sound a bit broken/granulated.

Comment: Oh my goodness Varun, that sounds AMAZING!